# How to close a workbook when i already set the filename and path in a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I already set the path and filename in a variable.

How to close the workbook using the filename that i already set?

This is the code:

```
Sub CLOSE_WORKBOOK_RAW()
Dim x As String
x = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

Dim Filepath As String
Filepath = ThisWorkbook.Path

Dim Filename As String
Filename = Filepath & "\" & x & ".xlsx"

Dim Filename2 As String
Filename2 = Filepath & "\" & x & ".xlsm"

Workbooks(Filename).Close Savechanges:=True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The short of your code appears to be embraced in

ThisWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True

All the rest of it just confuses the issue. However, here is the syntax for constructing a file name if, for example, you want to save the active workbook, usually while it is other than ThisWorkbook.

```
Sub Close_Workbook_Raw()

    Dim Filepath    As String           ' the path to save at
    Dim Filename    As String           ' the file's name
    Dim Ext         As String           ' the file name extension
    
    Filepath = ThisWorkbook.Path        ' or any other valid path
    Filename = Format(Date, "yymmdd ") & "MyFile's name"
    Ext = "xlsm"
    
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filepath & "\" & Filename & "." & Ext
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to close the workbook using the filename that I already set?

It depends

1. Is the workbook already saved once?
2. Is it a newly created workbook?
3. Also what is the format (xlsx/xlsm) you are going to use.

See this example for saving as `Xlsx`

```
Dim x As String
x = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

Dim Filepath As String
Filepath = ThisWorkbook.Path

Dim sFilename As String
sFilename = Filepath & "\" & x & ".xlsx"

Dim wb As Workbook

'~~> If already saved once
Set wb = Workbooks(x & ".xlsx")

'~~> If newly created and has the name `x`
Set wb = Workbooks(x)

wb.SaveAs Filename:=sFilename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
wb.Close (False)
```

**Note:**

> Filename2 = Filepath & "" & x & ".xlsm"

When using saving it as `.xlsm` you have to be very careful as you are going to use the original file name; basically trying to overwrite the same file.